# What type of method declaration is this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I just came across this line of code where a method is being instantiated without the use of either + or -. Can you please explain the code :

```
void *ABCD(NSString *xyz)
```

Comment: Aww. This is a C function. You know what's scary? People who don't even recognize basic C language constructs are trying to write iOS apps. That's scary. I suggest you take a step back, do yourself a favor and learn C before trying to continue iOS development. Don't do more than you can do at once, learn in small steps. [Start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), you won't regret it.

Comment: You might be interested in buying and reading [All the C You Need to Know
by Bill Dudney](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/all-the-c-you-need-to-know/id581989356?mt=11). iPad only. Written for Objective-C developers.

Answer (score 6):

That is a C function, of the type

```
 return_type  method_name (argument_list)
```

Your function returns a `void *` , a generic pointer, and takes an `NSString` arguement.

Comment: @Spectravideo328 Nah. It's Objective-C. C is a subset of Objective-C, so you can use C functions in Objective-C code. (After all, that's what the runtime does when it fools you into using nice methods and all that OO stuff.)

Comment: Yeah, I got that part. It just creeped me out to see an objective C type in the argument list of a C function!

Answer (score 0):

With a semicolon at the end, it's a C function declaration. If you follow the [spiral rule for C declarations](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html):

What is `ABCD`? `ABCD`is a function that takes a pointer to an `NSString` and returns a pointer to `void`. (ie. a pointer to elements of any data type).

Knowing the spiral rule is useful because C function declarations can be very complex.